# KnockoutJS foreach if

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

How can I do this:

```
<div class="boxes-container">
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
  <!-- ko if: DisplayCount < @itemsCount -->
     @Html.Raw("</div><div class='boxes-container'>")
     @{ itemsCount = 0;}
  <!-- /ko -->
   .....
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Now it's returning this error: **Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko foreach: Items**

Comment: Why do you need to do this ? Can't  you do it with something like that http://jsfiddle.net/4CSjK/ ?

Comment: no, I can't because I'm painting elements inside a div (boxes-container) and when I reach a certain number of elements I must close that container and start a new one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CSjK/1/) that could be a solution, in which `Grouped` is a computed so it will work even if `Items` would be an observableArray.

```
var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    self.DisplayCount = 3;
    self.Grouped = ko.computed(function () {
        var groups = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < self.Items.length; index = index + self.DisplayCount) {
            groups.push(self.Items.slice(index, index + self.DisplayCount));
        }
        return groups;
    });    
};
```

And view

```
<!-- ko foreach: Grouped -->
<div class='boxes-container'>
<!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4CSjK/1/)